# Left join dataframe in R based on the closest/nearest values in the right-hand-side dataframe

Tags: r, left-join, data-manipulation

```
t1 <- data.frame(
    team = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
    value1 = c(0.285, 0.37, 0.45, 0.42, 0.385),
    value2 = c(41, 51, 55, 61, 64)
)
  
pctiles = data.frame(
    pctile = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
    value1 = c(0.253, 0.291, 0.325, 0.336, 0.345, 0.35, 0.367, 0.39, 0.4, 0.41, 0.435),
    value2 = c(35, 50, 54, 57, 59, 61, 62, 65, 71, 81, 95)
)
```

we need to join `pctile` values from the `pctiles` dataframe onto the `t1` dataframe, based on which value in the `pctiles` dataframe that are closest to the values in the `t1` dataframe. For example, in `t1`, team A has a value1 of 0.285, which is closest with 0.291 in `pctiles$value1`. As a result, a `value1pctile` of 1 should be joined onto t1. By this logic, joining the closest pctile for each value, the output we are going for would be:

```
output_df <- data.frame(
    team = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
    value1 = c(0.285, 0.37, 0.45, 0.43, 0.385),
    value2 = c(41, 51, 55, 61, 64),
    value1pctile = c(1, 6, 10, 9, 7),
    value2pctile = c(0, 1, 3, 5, 7)
)
```

We are not worried about how situations are handled when a value in `t1` falls exactly between two values in `pctiles`. Either the higher or lower `pctile` value is just fine. How can we achieve this in R?

**Edit:** We are trying to use `fuzzy_left_join` but are hitting an error:

```
t1 <- fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
  t1, pctiles, 
  by = c("value1" = "value1"), 
  match_fun = "min_diff",
  distance_col = "dist"
)

> Error in which(m) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

it seems we are using `match_fun` and `distance_col` incorrectly.

Comment: You could mutate a new column on`t1` using `which.min(abs(pctiles$value1-value1))` to get the indexes, then use those for the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t1)
setDT(pctiles)

t1[, value1pctile := pctiles[.SD, on = "value1", roll = "nearest", pctile]]
t1[, value2pctile := pctiles[.SD, on = "value2", roll = "nearest", pctile]]

#      team value1 value2 value1pctile value2pctile
#    <char>  <num>  <num>        <num>        <num>
# 1:      a  0.285     41            1            0
# 2:      b  0.370     51            6            1
# 3:      c  0.450     55           10            2
# 4:      d  0.420     61            9            5
# 5:      e  0.385     64            7            7
```

Comment: this worked very sufficiently for us, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` option could also use `DescTools` `Closest` function to identify the closet value to join on. The argument `which` set to `TRUE` will return the row index of the closest value (instead of the value itself). The additional [1] added will only include one value, in case there are ties with multiple rows at the same distance away from a given value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DescTools)

t1 %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    value1pctile = pctiles[Closest(
      pctiles$value1,
      value1,
      which = TRUE), "pctile"][1],
    value2pctile = pctiles[Closest(
      pctiles$value2,
      value2,
      which = TRUE), "pctile"][1])
```

**Output**

```
  team  value1 value2 value1pctile value2pctile
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 a      0.285     41            1            0
2 b      0.37      51            6            1
3 c      0.45      55           10            2
4 d      0.42      61            9            5
5 e      0.385     64            7            7
```